# How to change the hue of a part of a scene?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a rather complex `QGraphicsScene` with a bunch of lines. I want a very specific zone to have a different hue. For instance, a blue line passing through this zone would be displayed as red *inside* the zone, but remain blue outside.

Naturally, it would be possible to just draw three lines instead of one, but this requires to write additional code which would determine whether a given line passes through the specific zone, and if yes, what are the coordinates of the intersection. Doable, but not the easiest thing to code. Therefore, if Qt can do that for me, it would be very nice.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area, but I would look to see if you can use a QOpenGLWidget with a shader effect to recolor a region of your scene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

My approach to the problem would be to:

1. Subclass [`QGraphicsRectItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsrectitem.html) if the zone should be rectangular and reimplement its paint method
2. Set the [composition mode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#compositionMode) of `QPainter` to an appropriate value, e.g. `QPainter::RasterOp_SourceAndNotDestination`:

   ```
    painter->setCompositionMode(QPainter::RasterOp_SourceAndNotDestination);
   ```

**Note:** For different shapes of the zone use different graphic items. You might also want to experiment with the composition modes to get different effects.

### Example

Here is an example I wrote for you to demonstrate how the proposed solution could be implemented:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QPainter>

class HueZone : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
public:
    explicit HueZone(QGraphicsItem *parent = nullptr) :
        QGraphicsRectItem(parent) {}

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *, QWidget *) override {
        painter->save();
        painter->setPen(pen());
        painter->setBrush(brush());
        painter->setCompositionMode(QPainter::RasterOp_SourceAndNotDestination);
        painter->drawRect(rect());
        painter->restore();
    }
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QMainWindow(parent) {
        auto *view = new QGraphicsView(this);
        auto *line = new QGraphicsLineItem(10, 20, 400, 300);
        auto *zone = new HueZone();

        line->setPen(QPen(Qt::blue));

        zone->setRect(100, 50, 200, 200);
        zone->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::red));
        zone->setPen(QPen(Qt::transparent));

        view->setScene(new QGraphicsScene(this));
        view->scene()->addItem(line);
        view->scene()->addItem(zone);

        setCentralWidget(view);
        resize(600, 480);
        setWindowTitle("Hue Zone");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

### Result

The above example produces the following result:

[image: line through a hue zone]